# Objects as parameters: Is there a simple way that explain this?

Tags: java, object-oriented

I tried to understand how objects can be passed as parameters but it was difficult for me. How can we pass an object as a parameter to a method of another object? I need to understand the idea behind this.

**updated:**

```
public class Student {}

public class Admin {

    private ArrayList<Student> students; 

    public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent)  
    {
       students.add(newStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code example you could provide that confused you?

Comment: @user3314958 why do you find the concepts of objects as parameters difficult (or any more so than an `int`)?

Comment: How can we pass an object (which has fields and methods) as a parameter for a method? It is confusing. At least int is just int!

Comment: @user3314958: And a Student is just a Student...  :)  There's a bit more involved (inheritance, for example), but you don't have to bother with it just yet if you don't want to (and a number of people would recommend that you use inheritance sparingly if at all anyway).

Comment: That's right but it has fields and methods and a lot code. Do we pass all that when we pass object as a parameter?

Comment: @user3314958: In Java?  Nope.  You pass a *reference* -- basically a handle to an object.  Not the whole object.  The reference thing does tend to confuse some people, since a copy of a reference points at the exact same object (so changes to the object appear through both references).  But it's not all that hard...just takes a little getting used to.

Comment: @user3314958: in some languages ints are objects.

Comment: @mouviciel: And in some languages, references/pointers are ints! (And if you want to be really pedantic, everything ever is an int, but it's the concept that's important!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Write a class with methods that take (i.e. has parameters) variables of specific type.
2. int, string, double, etc. are all types built-into Java.
3. Any class you write is also a type. The type kind/name is the name of your class
4. Create variables of whatever type, or class, you want.
5. Pass around variables of "your class name" type just like you pass around variables of int or string.
6. When you pass a variable of type int to a method the whole int goes.
7. When you pass a variable of type "your class name" to a method the whole thing goes.
8. A variable of type Student is like a suitcase. You grab hold of the Student by it's handle - the variable name. You pick up the suitcase by the handle and everything in it goes along for the ride. I.E. You pass the variable name (the handle) to a method and everything inside it goes along for the ride.

.

```
public class Student {
    public string Name;     //Name is a variable of type string
    public int Age;         //Age is a variable of type int

    public Student(string name, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

public string EinsteinName;    //EinsteinName is a variable of type string
public int EinsteinAge;    //EinsteinAge is a variable of type int
public Student Albert;     //Albert is a variable of type Student

EinsteinName = "Albert Einstein"; //the variable named EinsteinName is given a value
EinsteinAge = 114;   //the variable named EinsteinAge is given a value

Albert = new Student(EinsteinName, EinsteinAge);
     //the variable named Albert is given a value.

     // above, the variables EinsteinName(a string) and EinsteinAge (an int)
     // are passed into the method Student. This method creates a Student object. It's a constructor.
     // Thus the variable Albert (a Student) is given a value.

// then some other stuff happens.

EnrollStudent(Albert);

// above, Albert (a variable of type Student) 
//is passed to the EnrollStudent method. Albert has details 
//inside like Name and Age -  but all that is inside the suitcase 
//so when we pass Albert all the stuff inside goes along.
```